# PHP get function not grabbing parameter

Tags: php, url, get

So... I have the following code which is very simple:

```
<?php echo $_GET["base_grant_url"] ?>
```

Currently, this is just for testing.  I am having problems though... when the following URLs tested with:

```
http://localhost/?base_grant_url=htt%3A%2F%2Fn00.test.com
http://localhost/?base_grant_url=http%3A%2F%2Fn00
```

The parameter is printed properly.  Notice the missing "p" in the first and no "." characters in the parameter in the second.  When the following 2 URLs are passed:

```
http://localhost/?base_grant_url=http%3A%2F%2Fn00.test.com
http://localhost/?base_grant_url=http%3A%2F%2Fn00.
```

Both of these addresses print back absolutely nothing... it took me quite a while to narrow my problem down to this as this is a small part of a larger scenario but this is what I am currently trying to correct.  Why am I unable to get the parameters when they are incorrect but when they have HTTP and a "." character in them... the $_GET function fails?  Is there some common convention I am missing or some simple fix to this problem?

EDIT:  So after testing on a local test server it works fine.  I will be contacting my hosting provider to try and find the issue.

as for the output for print_r... here is the code and output:

CODE:

```
echo "Base Grant URL = ";
echo $_GET["base_grant_url"];
echo " -=- GET = ";
print_r($_GET);
```

Test 1 (no "." in parameter also this works if http is not in parameter):

```
URL: http://testserver.com/?base_grant_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexamplecom%2Fsplash%2Flogin%2F%3Fmauth%3DABCDEFG123456
OUTPUT: Base Grant URL = https://examplecom/splash/login/?mauth=ABCDEFG123456 -=- GET = Array ( [base_grant_url] => https://examplecom/splash/login/?mauth=ABCDEFG123456 )
```

Test 2 (with proper URL):

```
URL: http://testserver.com/?base_grant_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsplash%2Flogin%2F%3Fmauth%3DABCDEFG123456
OUTPUT: Base Grant URL = -=- GET = Array ( )
```

Comment: Working fine for me, may be some sever issue

Comment: it works perfect... no issue in getting the base_grant_url value...

Comment: It works fine. I hope you're using the right URL. For example if you wrote that in test.php you use `http://localhost/test.php?base_grant_url=htt%3A%2F%2Fn00.test.com`

Comment: Have you got a RewriteRule that might strip possibly dangerous Query strings or supposedly protects against injections?

Comment: I had some injection protection initially and then was having this issue.  So I stripped it down a little bit at a time to this very basic form until I came to this problem and I found what the issue was.  Since others are not having the issue I am guessing it is a problem with the PHP implementation on my host.  Was working on a live test server before... I will test on a test server on my local machine next to ensure that I as others here do not have problems grabbing the variable and then I will just contact my hosting company.

Comment: Also... now that I think about it... the parameter is only used to save to a session variable and then after a page redirection the saved variable is then just used to rewrite their destination redirect address.  In a case like that... would injection protection even be needed?  Its not used for any database queries or the like.  Only re divulged via the session it was saved to on the next page to rewrite a url.  Any custom modification would just essentially redirect their own destination.

Comment: Could you show the output of `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>`?

Comment: Or cloud you post your modules installed `linux> php -m`? suhosin is installed? Apache mod_security?

Comment: This is not a solution to empty $_GET but why you don't encode URL with something like base64_encode/decode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was my website hosting company that had some mod security rules enabled on the server to protect against what they call "Generic PHP code injections". Not sure I agree that there is a risk, but they disabled it and my scripts started working.